# How to update OpenJDK on RHEL

Tags: redhat, java

I need to update OpenJDK for one of the company servers (RHEL 6).

It is currently running **OpenJDK 1.7.0_09**  but I need to upgrade to **OpenJDK 1.7.0_45**

I read some tutorials but they seem to use yum to carry this out but the server is not configured so that it is registered on the Red Hat subscription network.

Is there any way to achieve this manually?

Comment: If you don't have a RHEL subscription, you should *really* use CentOS et al. instead to allow for easy updates.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a RHEL subscription then you can login into your RH account and download the RPM then install it with `yum -y install x.y.z.rpm`. Otherwise, you can also take the package from a CentOS repository, it should be 100% compatible. For example [this URL](http://mirrors.kernel.org/centos/6.5/updates/x86_64/Packages/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.45-2.4.3.4.el6_5.x86_64.rpm). By the way, the latest version is .65 and you should really use that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to download the relevant RPMs from a CentOS mirror and install by hand, but this might end up in more problems due to (version) dependency issues.

It might even be possible to switch the repos from RHEL to CentOS and just update as usual, but I would be wary about that.

Answer (score 0):

Serverfault is for business environment, so the optimal solution here is to purchase Red Hat support and use it.

This way you redirect some of your employers money to open source development, a good thing.

If the security rules stand in the way, you can use a regular proxy with `yum`. If more security is required, you can set up your own Spacewalk repository, or get an entire ISO, configure it as a repository and `yum update` from that ISO.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have outbound internet access from the machine? If so, you can download the RedHat OpenJDK RPM from [here](http://www.rpmseek.com/rpm-pl/java-1.7.0-openjdk.html?hl=com&cx=0::) and then run `rpm -i open_jdk_file_name.rpm`.

I believe this will perform an upgrade, but you can always run `rpm -e old_java_package_name` first to remove the old version before installing the new.

Comment: I went to the link you gave me and I don't understand some part of the rpm files.. java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.45-2.4.3.4.el6_5.src.rpm  in this file name, what does the bit 2.4.3.4.el6_5.src mean? Which one do I pick?

Comment: I don't know what the 2.4.3.4 bit means but I would always pick the latest one there is. However, you need to make sure you match "el6" bit to the version of RedHat you're running (el6 = Version 6).

Comment: @dK3: The `src` part means this is the source code, not a binary package, and not what you want. `el6` means for `RHEL 6` and `2.4.3.4` is a RPM version number.

Comment: alright.. thanks for the details :) Somehow I can only see .src.rpm files for RHEL..

Comment: Yes I didn't notice that until now. It was a quick google to get you going. Hopefully you can find the binary RPM elsewhere

Comment: You should not use rpm directly. Always use yum!